# How to solve numerically a maximum vector with constraints?

Tags: r, finance, numerical-methods, portfolio

I'm doing financial engineering on R and I want to build a Market Neutral portfolio. My portfolio has 10 assets, whose betas are known (denoted b1,b2,...b10) and returns are known too (r1,r2,...r10). My goal is to optimize the return portfolio by adjusting weights, whose can be positive or negative. I have 2 weights that are already known w1=2 and w10=-1 (Short). The constraints are :

```
2*b1+w2*b2+w3*b3+w4*b4+w5*b5+w6*b6+w7*b7+w8*b8+w9*b9-b10=0
```

and

```
2+w2+w3+w4+w5+w6+w7+w8+w9-1 = 1 (The sum of weights equal 1)
```

the equation to maximize is :

```
max(R = 2r1+w2r2+w3r3+w4r4+w5r5+w6r6+w7r7+w8r8+w9r9-r10)
```

I wanted to solve it numerically with assignining a matrix of weights with value included between (-10 to 10) for each of the 8 unknown `w2 to w9`and assigning a different colour if the combinaison does not match the constraints but **I was wondering if there is a package that could allow me to calculate it without to pass by a complex matrix formation.**

```
betas=c(0.6118876,0.7376193,0.8401905,0.9746638,1.022843,1.097142,1.166615,1.274656,1.389989,1.604495)
returns = c(1.103170e-01,1.054401e-01,1.140598e-01,1.243254e-01,1.100530e-01,1.188003e-01,1.008402e-01,1.215204e-01,1.040005e-01,9.985965e-02)
w1=2
w10=-1
```

Comment: I am still curious to see if there is a possibility to solve it through R. Despite hours, I have not found